# Making a table with horizontal line only

Tags: html, css

How can I build a `table` in HTML and CSS only with the **horizontal** lines? I've tried so much stuff but I cant get it to work.

Something like this:

**Name**  (space)    Age

---

Andre (space) 12

---

Jose (space) 16

---

Comment: i've trie this code:  td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   
    border-collapse: collapse;
}​

but the line only appears under each <td> and not in all the row like i wanted. i tried to put in the css code tr instead td but it doesnt work

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Potentially like this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mJAF7/1/)):

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

th {
    text-align: left;    
}
```

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Jose</td>
            <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alberto</td>
            <td>32</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ``table, tr {
 border: 1px solid black;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
border-collapse: collapse;
} ``

This works perfectly fine.

Comment: `border-collapse: collapse;` this is crazy

Answer (score 5):

the css for the horizontal dividers is:

```
th, td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

see: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp